# DiffUtil Callback with Cursor closed to early

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, cursor, diff

I try the new `DiffUtil` to get the differences in a `RecyclerView.Adapter`. But the old cursor on a reload is closed before the diff can be calculated and I don't know why. This [`CursorCallback`](https://gist.github.com/NikolaDespotoski/9e4f76c58264ffaf5e9f1eb6096b07ba) is the `Callback` base, this [`Adapter`](https://gist.github.com/skyfishjy/443b7448f59be978bc59) is my base and here is my activity code:

```
public class RecyclerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ItemAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recycler);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize( true );
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this) );
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter = new ItemAdapter(this));
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new ItemAnimator());

        ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleItemTouchCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {

            @Override
            public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
                long id = recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemId( viewHolder.getAdapterPosition() );
                viewHolder.itemView.getContext().getContentResolver().delete(ContentUris.withAppendedId(CategoryContract.CONTENT_URI, id), null, null);
            }
        };
        ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleItemTouchCallback);
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return new CursorLoader(this, CategoryContract.CONTENT_URI, CategoryContract.PROJECTION, null, null, CategoryContract.COLUMN_ID + " DESC");
    }

    public void addItem( View button ) {
        int count = recyclerView != null ? recyclerView.getChildCount() : 0;
        ContentValues v = new ContentValues(1);
        v.put(CategoryContract.COLUMN_NAME, "Foo Nr. " + count);
        getContentResolver().insert(CategoryContract.CONTENT_URI, v);
    }

    private Task setter;

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished( final Loader<Cursor> loader, final Cursor data) {
        if( setter != null) {
            setter.cancel(true);
        }

        setter = new Task( adapter );
        AsyncTaskCompat.executeParallel(setter, adapter.getCursor(), data );
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        adapter.changeCursor(null);
    }

    public static class Task extends AsyncTask<Cursor, Void, Pair<Cursor, DiffUtil.DiffResult>> {
        private final CursorRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;

        Task(CursorRecyclerViewAdapter adapter) {
            this.adapter = adapter;
        }

        @Override
        protected Pair<Cursor, DiffUtil.DiffResult> doInBackground(Cursor... params) {
            return Pair.create( params[1], DiffUtil.calculateDiff( new ItemCallback( params[0], params[1]) ) );
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Pair<Cursor, DiffUtil.DiffResult> diffResult) {
            if( isCancelled() )
                return;
            adapter.swapCursor(diffResult.first);
            diffResult.second.dispatchUpdatesTo(adapter);
        }
    }

    public static class ItemAdapter extends CursorRecyclerViewAdapter<ItemHolder>
    {
        ItemAdapter( Context context ) {
            super(context, null);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ItemHolder viewHolder, Cursor cursor) {
            CategoryModel model = CategoryModel.FACTORY.createFromCursor( cursor );
            viewHolder.textView.setText( model.getId() + " - " + model.getName() );
        }

        @Override
        public ItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return new ItemHolder(LayoutInflater.from( parent.getContext() ).inflate( R.layout.item, parent, false ));
        }
    }

    public static class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;

        ItemHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = ( TextView ) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        }
    }

    public static class ItemCallback extends CursorCallback<Cursor> {
        public ItemCallback(Cursor newCursor, Cursor oldCursor) {
            super(newCursor, oldCursor);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean areRowContentsTheSame(Cursor oldCursor, Cursor newCursor) {
            CategoryModel oldCategory = CategoryModel.FACTORY.createFromCursor(oldCursor);
            CategoryModel newCategory = CategoryModel.FACTORY.createFromCursor(newCursor);
            return oldCategory.getName().equals( newCategory.getName() );
        }

        @Override
        public boolean areCursorRowsTheSame(Cursor oldCursor, Cursor newCursor) {
            return oldCursor.getLong(0) == newCursor.getLong(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is welcome. Maybe the old cursor is closed when a new cursor with same query is returned. The cursor is open at the moment I call `getCursor()` in `onLoadFinished()` but closed inside `CursorCallback` on first usage.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K: The problem still exists. Its only a change for readability and nothing else.

Comment: @Happo: Ok, user1643723 answer is fine i think.

Comment: For the record, it's a very bad idea to use DiffUtil with a windowed Cursor (like SQLiteCursor) because the purpose of these cursors is to load the data lazily from the database, while DiffUtil requires instant random access to any part of a list so everything needs to be loaded entirely into memory first. If your Cursor is an SQLiteCursor, transfer the entire cursor data to a List first or don't use DiffUtil.

Comment: Also: you are perfoming the Diff on a background thread but at the same time the old Cursor is still used on the main thread by the RecyclerView. This means you are accessing the same Cursor on 2 different threads at the same time and you will have a race condition when the RecyclerView and DiffUtil change the Cursor position at the same time.

Comment: @BladeCoder thank you for the tips and the concurrency hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have encountered an expected behaviour of `CursorLoader` — they close the old Cursor after another one arrives, whether you are currently using it or not.

The event sequence in your case is like this:

1. You get the (still open) Cursor and start a diff computation in some background thread X of AsyncTask thread pool
2. Something somewhere calls `ContentResolver.notifyChanged`
3. The CursorLoader is loading a new Cursor in another background thread Y. That new Cursor is posted to onLoadFinished and, probably, already swapped into the list adapter.
4. CursorLoader closes old Cursor.
5. Your background thread X does not know about point 2,3 and keeps using old Cursor until it finds out that it is closed by CursorLoader. An Exception is thrown.

In order to keep using the Cursor from background thread, you will have to manually manage your Cursor (without aid of CursorLoader): close it yourself if configuration change or onDestroy happen.

Alternatively, just intercept the exception and treat it as a sign that your background diff computation is being cancelled (it will shortly be performed for another Cursor anyway).